# Accents as question mark after server update

Tags: php, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I got a server with an old PHP app that is showing the accents like á-é-í-ó-ú as � but only if the word is written with the accent. "**Búsqueda**"

There are other cases where words are written by using entity characters like `B&uacute!squeda` the website shows them correctly

- Those accents are in the files of the app not in a DB
- PHP files header charset are iso-8859-1 ( `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'>`)
- PHP Version 5.6
- PHP Charset UTF-8
- No PHP files backup from old server

In this image

**Descripción** is written as `Descripci&oacute;n` and **Autorizaci�n** as `Autorización`

PHP charset in **utf-8** and header **charset=iso-8859-1**

Error #1:
[image]

If I force PHP or the header to iso-8859-1

Error #2:
[image]

The word **Descripción** comes from a ini file stored as `Descripci&oacute;n` and and **Autorizaci�n** in a PHP+HTML file as `Autorización`

This is driving me crazy. Is there any way I can have two charsets at the same time. I'm considering editing the files so the system will use only one charset but that could means weeks of work.

Sorry for my English, I'm not native speaker.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you answer my unanswered question from [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62085405/accents-as-question-mark-after-server-update)? Click View Source (or equivalent) in your browser and check whether your "ó" is *really* `&oacute;`, or "ó". If you're reading it from an INI file, there are obviously some steps involved there, and I suspect you're HTML-decoding it at some point.

Comment: Hello, I see the **Descripción** for the word written as `Descripci&oacute;n`  and Autorizaci�n for the word written as **Autorización**. In this moment PHP = utf-8

Comment: That is positively bizarre and rather inexplicable. Try to debug step by step as low-level as possible, e.g. using curl to request the page and inspecting the result in a hex editor…